# Slider Position Issue in HTML5 and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to place the main slider behind main navigation so I have set navigation `position` to `fixed` and the slider position to absolute. It works fine but for some reason, the entire footer element moves below navigation and on the slider. I have tried giving `min-width` and display `block` to the slider but it did not work.

Here is my sample code.

**Navigation HTML:**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#">Item 3</a>
</nav>
```

**Slider HTML:**

```
<div class="slider">
  Slider Items Here
</div>
```

**Footer Html:**

```
<footer>
</footer>
```

**CSS Code**

```
nav {
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 600px;
    display: block;
}

footer {
    display: block;
}
```

**Here is how it looks right now:**

[image]

Comment: Due to the fact that the position is set to absolute, it's not taken in consideration into the positioning others elements.

Comment: @Sorikairo The only way I can place the slider behind the navigation is to set `position` as `absolute` for the slider. I have tried setting different position for the footer but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I would advice you to use position absolute on the navigation and footer instead of the slider :) Fixing the first on top and the latter on bottom

Comment: @Sorikairo I was able to fix it with your method :)

Comment: Do you mind if a create an answer and you accept it ? Reputation and stuffs (also it makes it visible for others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment, you shoud set the header and footer position to `absolute` (the former at the top and the latter at the bottom), and remove the `absolute` from the slider.

Then your slider will be full-page, and header and footer will always be at the right position.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  height: 30px;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

main {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

footer {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>I'm a 30px tall header</header>
  <main>I'm the main-content filling the void!</main>
  <footer>I'm a 30px tall footer</footer>
</div>
```

```
Like This ......You want!!
at the top of Header and inside header Nav Bar ... In Main Section Slider And Below Footer ! 

http://codepen.io/enjikaka/pen/zxdYjX
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15789370)

Comment: If You Know The Ans Then Write Here ... Don't Give Just Suggestion only .. I Try To My Level Best @ABusyProgrammer

Comment: There was nothing wrong with your code. You simply had to post it directly in your post. And there is no need to be rude, read [__How to post a good answer on StackOverflow__](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)